# Is there a free online Virtual OS service?

Tags: webapp-rec

I was using a free [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/) pro account, and they provided operating systems (including Windows 7, Windows XP, and Ubuntu) which I could access from anywhere in the browser.

Are there any other services like this?

Comment: What happened to this free offering, have they pulled it or was it just a promotion or so?

Comment: i am not sure why they pulled it, i sent them asking about that but they didn't reply, they are now offering just a limited number of days beta version, then you must pay to get the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Eye OS](http://eyeos.org). And its free as well! Doesn't let you run Windows, Linux or any of the other operating systems though.

Comment: hoped its running real OSs, because i wanted it for testing applications i write or open websites from different OSs, by the way it's nice to know Eye OS. +1

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there is anything that is completely free, but [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) can be very cheap if you are not using very much bandwidth and you only need it for limited time. It would depend on what you need to use it for.

Do you want something that you want up and running 24 hours a day or something that you can use to test drive? EC2 will charge $0.09/hour for Linux and $0.12/hour for Windows. (as long as bandwidth is less then 1 GB/month)

Comment: how does this work? they give you a Vm you can remotely access? can I just open it 1 hour a day and pay 12c a day?

Comment: @RodH257 Basically, yes and yes. But instead of believing me go to http://aws.amazon.com/free/ and check it yourself for free: *To help new AWS customers get started in the cloud, AWS is introducing a new free usage tier. New AWS customers will be able to run a free Amazon EC2 Micro Instance for a year, while also leveraging a new free usage tier for Amazon S3, Amazon EBS, Amazon ELB, and AWS data transfer. AWS’s free usage tier can be used for anything you want to run in the cloud: launch new applications, test existing applications in the cloud, or simply gain hands-on experience with AWS.*

Answer (score 2):

I would watch [StackVM](http://stackvm.com/).  They should have this functionality up shortly.  Read about what they are doing [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/i-am-doing-a-startup).

Comment: what a great idea! hope it works out well for them

Answer (score 0):

[BrowserCam](http://www.browsercam.com/Default2.aspx) has a number of offerings for testing websites/programs on different OS's.

They range from free screenshots, to full remote desktop access.

Answer (score 0):

[iCloud OS](http://www.icloud.com)

It has its own OS